# нужно взять среднее от колонки,которая создается вот этой строчкой: Count(Priem.[ID_klienta]) as kol

Tags: mysql

Так выглядит мой запрос:

```
Select Seller.FIO as 'ФИО продавца'
Count(Priem.[ID_klienta]) as kol
From (Priem left join Saller on Priem.[ID_klienta]= Saller.ID_saller)
Group by Seller.FIO;
```

и мне нужно взять среднее от колонки, которая создается вот этой строчкой:

```
Count(Priem.[ID_klienta]) as kol
```